# Как изменить цвет строк таблицы в Swift

Tags: swift

Для одной строки выбираю цвет, все работает. Если создаю вторую строку и задаю другой цвет, то первая меняет свой цвет и обе одного цвета. Как сделать так, чтобы цвета были разные?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Функция получения цвета

```
@IBAction func backgroundColor(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if let well = sender as? NSColorWell {
        let color = well.color
        MQTTSubscribeVC.preferenceTableColor = color

TableBgColorChangedNotification), object: self)
    }
}
```

Отображение

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {

cell.messageLabel.backgroundColor = color.preferenceTableColor
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задайте tag для каждой строки, и потом для каждой строки с нужным тэгом установить нужный цвет.

```
cell.tag = 1
if cell.tag == 1 {
   cell.backgroundColor = color
}
```

Более Swifty это через switch:

```
switch cell.tag {
case 1:
cell.backgroundColor = color1
case 2:
cell.backgroundColor = color2
default:
break
}
```

Comment: Строк может быть сколько угодно каждую не пронумеровать

Comment: cell.tag = indexPath.row